# DB Design - overriding values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am trying to determine if my current design makes the most sense. I have a pricing table that will always have a default value for a given product (ProductId). Depending on multiple environments, the price could be overwritten.

Given this table:

[image: table & data]

I would like to get the appropriate prices based on a given city, county, state or default. This is somewhat contrived as Type and Priority represent the same thing and would probably be limited to the int and indexed (no need for strings). I use the INT because it allows me to sort and prioritize which one to select from the inner query's TOP. Using this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, prices.Price
FROM [CCC].[Prices] p CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT TOP 1 Price 
   FROM [CCC].[Prices] p2 
   WHERE p.ProductId = p2.ProductId 
     AND (Type = 'Default' 
       OR (Type = 'City' AND TypeId = 553) 
       OR (Type = 'State' AND TypeId = '4'))
   ORDER BY [Priority] DESC
) prices
```

Gets me exactly what I am looking for:

[image]

---

The two methods I am considering are:

All in the app code (having all values available and then based on null values find the most appropriate price.

In SQL (demonstrated above), taking the top value ordered by priority in desc
And in SQL using a cross apply to get all the prices (versus a single record). Coalesce (addressing posted answer) is also a solution, but coalesce can be expansive I have found in the past. I prefer this version.

**Are there other methods or patterns that I should consider?**

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `cross apply`, you can do the work in SQL Server.  Something like this is one approach:

```
select t.*, p.price
from t cross join
     (select
      from pricing p
      where p.productid = t.productid and
            (p.city = t.city or
             p.county = t.county and p.city is null or
             p.state = t.state and p.county is null and t.county is null or
             p.state is null
            )
      order by (case when p.city is not null then 1
                     when p.county is not null then 2
                     when p.state is not null then 3
                     else 4
                end)
     ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern city, county, state, default is fix, you cuold do it by outer joins and coalesce, something like this:

```
select t.*, coalesce(city.price, county.price, state.price, defaulttab.price) as price
 from t left outer join citytab as city  t.productid = city.productid
                                          and on t.city = city.city 
        left outer join countytab as county  on t.productid = county.productid
                                          and t.county = county.county
        left outer join statetab as state on  t.productid = state.productid
                                          and t.state = state.state
        join defautlttab on t.productid = defaulttab.productid
```

Comment: I considered this version and will test against it, but I think cross apply performs better from my experience. I need a bigger test table to know for sure.